# Get Absolute Position of element within the window in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-positioning

I would like to get the absolute position of an element in relation to the window/root element when it is double clicked. The element's relative position within it's parent is all I can seem to get to, and what I'm trying to get to is the point relative to the window.  I've seen solutions of how to get a the point of an element on the screen, but not in the window.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I think what BrandonS wants is not the position of the *mouse* relative to the root element, but rather the position of some descendant element.

For that, there is the [TransformToAncestor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.transformtoancestor.aspx) method:

```
Point relativePoint = myVisual.TransformToAncestor(rootVisual)
                              .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Where `myVisual` is the element that was just double-clicked, and `rootVisual` is Application.Current.MainWindow or whatever you want the position relative to.

Comment: Hi i tried this and i get the following exception: System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=The specified Visual is not an ancestor of this Visual.
  Source=PresentationCore Any idea?

Comment: Visual.TransformToAncestor will only work if you pass in a containing Visual.  If you want the relative position of two elements and one doesn't contain the other, you can use Visual.TransformToVisual instead.

Comment: TransformToVisual still requires a common ancestor which can be problematic if the control is in a popup

Comment: Super intuitive! Can't they wrap this in a "GetRelativePosition" call? :-) Thanks for the help. +1

Comment: @Paul - Try writing an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)!

Comment: @cod3monk3y - or perhaps, maybe if Microsoft open sources WPF, I'll send them a pull request :-)

Answer (score 52):

To get the absolute position of an UI element within the window you can use:

```
Point position = desiredElement.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d));
```

If you are within a User Control, and simply want relative position of the UI element within that control, simply use:

```
Point position = desiredElement.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d)),
controlPosition = this.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d));

position.X -= controlPosition.X;
position.Y -= controlPosition.Y;
```

Comment: Note that this probably doesn't do what you expect if your display scaling isn't set to 100% (ie on high DPI screens).

Answer (score 21):

Add this method to a static class:

```
 public static Rect GetAbsolutePlacement(this FrameworkElement element, bool relativeToScreen = false)
    {
        var absolutePos = element.PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
        if (relativeToScreen)
        {
            return new Rect(absolutePos.X, absolutePos.Y, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);
        }
        var posMW = Application.Current.MainWindow.PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
        absolutePos = new System.Windows.Point(absolutePos.X - posMW.X, absolutePos.Y - posMW.Y);
        return new Rect(absolutePos.X, absolutePos.Y, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);
    }
```

Set `relativeToScreen` paramater to `true` for placement from top left corner of whole screen or to `false` for placement from top left corner of application window.

Comment: This works fantastically! I'm using this with an animation that slides an image on- or off-screen by modifying the `RenderTransform` of the element, and therefore it needs to know the absolute position of the element on the screen.

Answer (score 10):

Since .NET 3.0, you can simply use `*yourElement*.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), *theContainerOfYourChoice*)`.

This will give you the point 0, 0 of your button, but towards the container.
(You can also give an other point that 0, 0)

[Check here for the doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint)

Answer (score 0):

```
childObj.MouseDown += (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) =>
{
    Vector parent = (Vector)e.GetPosition(parentObj);
    Vector child = (Vector)e.GetPosition(childObj); // sender
    Point childPosition = (Point)(parent - child);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Hm.
You have to specify window you clicked in `Mouse.GetPosition(IInputElement relativeTo)`
Following code works well for me

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        Point p = e.GetPosition(this);
    }
```

I suspect that you need to refer to the window not from it own class but from other point of the application. In this case `Application.Current.MainWindow` will help you.

Comment: Even though it's not what the author asked for, it got me on the right track, thanks