# Find the center of a uielement in wpf

Tags: wpf, uielement

How can I find the center of a `UIElement` in wpf?

Answer (score 6):

You can get absolute position of the control like this

```
Point relativePoint = myVisual.TransformToAncestor(rootVisual)
                              .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

where `myVisual` is your control and `rootVisual` is the parent control(see [Get Absolute Position of element within the window in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386731/get-absolute-position-of-element-within-the-window-in-wpf)), so you can find the center of the uielement like this

```
Point pt = new Point(relativePoint.X + myVisual.ActualWidth/2, relativePoint.Y + myVisual.ActualHeight/2);
```

Comment: Does not work for a Path. Still looking for an answer.
Thanks

Comment: You'd need to wrote the the furthest extents of the path and get its centroid.  All geometry

Answer (score 0):

Building off @ArsenMkrt,

```
Point center = myVisual.TransformToAncestor(rootVisual).Transform(new Point(myVisual.ActualWidth / 2, myVisual.ActualHeight / 2));
```