# How to get XY coordinates of a control at runtime in WPF?

Tags: wpf

How to get XY coordinates of a control at runtime in WPF ?

Comment: this is a duplicated question

Answer (score 86, accepted):

For that, there is the TransformToAncestor method:

```
Point relativePoint = myVisual.TransformToAncestor(rootVisual)
                          .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Where `myVisual` is the element you want to get the position of, and `rootVisual` is `Application.Current.MainWindow` or whatever you want the position relative to.

reference link:
[Get Absolute Position of element within the window in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386731/get-absolute-position-of-element-within-the-window-in-wpf)