# WPF - Center control (label) within Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, label

Greetings

I'm trying to fix the positioning of controls in my WPF Application. In my application I have several Labels which each are in a different Canvas. I'm trying to center the label within the canvas. The code I currently have for one Label is the following:

```
<Canvas Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,0,0" Name="canvasPlayer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" >
    <Label Content="" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Eurostile LT ExtendedTwo" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0" Name="labelPlayer1Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" />
</Canvas>
```

Now for starters the problem with this is that it does not center the text at all, it stays at the original position. What I'm trying to achieve is to center the content of the label in that canvas BUT it cannot exceed the width of the canvas.

Helpful suggestions are welcomed! If you have any comments regarding my thinking pattern to solve this issue please do notify me as well!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why did you use Canvas? do you have to draw something? use Grid insted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Absolute Position of element within the window in wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386731/get-absolute-position-of-element-within-the-window-in-wpf)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't use Canvas for this. Alignment properties and margins will have no effect on elements laid out in a Canvas. What you should use instead is a Grid. Canvas is not particularly useful for most layout scenarios.

```
<Grid Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,0,0" 
      Name="canvasPlayer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" >
    <Label Content="" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" 
           FontFamily="Eurostile LT ExtendedTwo" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0" 
           Name="labelPlayer1Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I used a canvas to select the area in which it had to center. I guess i'll have to line out my grid entirely with rows and columns then i guess? Thank you for the reply btw!

Comment: You don't actually need to create the rows and columns if you don't want to (although it does make for much cleaner layouts.) You can just use margins and alignment properties inside of a 1x1 Grid. This is actually what the WPF designer in Visual Studio and Blend do by default.

Comment: Most often than not, the following sentence applies to my experience with WPF: "Well, kid, you THINK you want a Canvas, but actually you don't (you just don't know this yet)..." Quite irritating, indeed (specially when mixing Canvas and ViewBox, sort of a "layout short-circuit")...