# Label with Canvas X and Y coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, mouseover

I'm working in a WPF application in C#, based on quite a complicated XAML, and I'm trying to modify the location on the canvas of a component. Now my component is gone, which might have two reasons:

- either I did something wrong and my component is gone indeed.
- or I did nothing wrong and my component is hidden behind some other component.

You might say "That's easy! Just put it somewhere where there are no other components." but that's the problem: due to some issues in the XAML I can't show it in design view because it makes my Visual Studio crash.
"So what? Just have a look at the rest of your components and try to find out." but also this is not easy, due to the myriad of components on my screen.

When launching the application, I see some holes in the canvas, but I can't find out the X and Y coordinates (`Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` values) of those locations.
In order to find those, I would like to have some label on my canvas, which shows X and Y coordinates of the mouse, whenever I move my mouse over that canvas.

Although this seems relatively simple, due to my lack of XAML knowledge I have no idea how to do this.

Does anybody know how to add a `Label` on a XAML `Canvas`, reacting on ±`MouseOver` events and showing `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` values?

**Attempt 1:**

I can confirm that this is not working: (`OnMouseOver` is not known)

```
<Canvas Height="3000" Width="7000" 
        OnMouseOver="XY_Pos.Text='X : [' + Self.Left + '], Y : [' + Self.Top + ']'">
  <Label x:Name="XY_pos" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100"/>
```

**Attempt 2:**

Also this is not working:

In the xaml:

```
<Canvas Height="3000" Width="7000"
        ToolTipOpening='Canvas_ToolTipOpening' 
        ToolTipService.ToolTip='Testing'>
  <Label x:Name="XY_pos" 
         Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100"/>
```

In the corresponding `xaml.cs` file:

```
private void Canvas_ToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    XY_pos.Content = $"X=[{((Canvas)sender).Left}], Y=[{((Canvas)sender).Top}}]";
}
```

This latter code recognises `XY_pos`, but generated `CS1061` errors on the `Left` and `Top` properties.

Not only that, but I'm debugging this function: now it seems that `sender` is of type `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas` and that type does not have a `Left` or a `Top` property. Is this correct? In order to position a control on a `Canvas` you need to fill in the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties, but a `Canvas` object does not even have a `Left` and a `Top` property???

Thanks in advance

XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas1" MouseMove="hit spacebar here then select from the dropdown create new event handler">
```

C#:
find the new event handler method with the name of the one created in the MouseMove property in the XAML.

```
canvas1_MouseMove(object sender, e MouseEventArgs) method:
{
var mousePos = e.GetPosition(canvas1);
canvas1.ToolTip = mousePos.X.ToString() + " " + mousepos.Y.ToString();
}
```

this should make a tooltip appear whenever the mouse is over the canvas that has the X and Y coordinates of the mouse relative to the canvas. at may need some minor tweaks but that's worked for me in the past.
Good Luck!

P.S
can confirm this will work and here is the code I used to test it and will round the values to whole number rather than 5 decimal points:

```
private void canvas1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var mousePos = e.GetPosition(canvas1);
    canvas1.ToolTip = "X = " + ((int)mousePos.X).ToString() + "  ||  Y = " + ((int)mousePos.Y).ToString();
}
```

Also you can set the element position in the codebehind with

```
UIElement uIElement = new UIElement();
    canvas1.Children.Add(uIElement);
    Canvas.SetLeft(uIElement, 100);
    Canvas.SetTop(uIElement, 100);
```

Comment: You guys were right not to answer, as I did not provide with any effort. I've edited my question, adding some thing which does completely not work but which clearly explains what I mean.

Comment: I know this is a long shot and maybe a bit far fetched but why exactly are you using canvas? I personally have never used wpf, but this thread might give you a little nudge forward. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4456848/18278998

Comment: Canvas.Left and .Top are so-called attached properties that are set on the child elements of a Canvas, not on the Canvas itself. The Canvas class provides static get and set methods for these properties that work on any type of UIElement.