# How to find a data-binded ListBoxItem position?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox` that its `ItemsSource` is given from a class based on the data binded items template. I want to find `ListBox.SelectedItem` position relative to the `ListBox`. Since I've used a class to feed `ItemsSource`, I'm not be able to cast `ListBox.SelectedItem` *(which has a type of `object`)* to the `ListBoxItem`. *(Instead I should cast it to the source class type.)*

What's the way? -Thanks

---

***Details:** (Arbitrary)*

There is a `ListBox` which implements a `Style` like so:

```
<Style x:Key="MyListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border ...>
                    <StackPanel ...>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ItemImageSource}" .../>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemTitle}" .../>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `ListBox` has been used as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyListBoxStyle}"/>
```

Also there is a class that supports `MyListBox` data-binding info:

```
internal class MyListBoxItemBinding
{
    public string ItemTitle { get; set; }

    public ImageSource ItemImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

And to feed the `MyListBox`:

```
MyListBox.ItemsSource = new List<MyListBoxItemBinding> { /* some items */ };
```

Now, how can I find `MyListBox.SelectedItem` location relative to the `MyListBox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) to get a reference to the item container generator for your `ListBox` (this is the object that creates wrappers for all your databound objects).

Then, use the [`ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem.aspx) method to get a reference to the `UIElement` that represents the selected `ListBoxItem`.

Finally, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386731/get-absolute-position-of-element-within-the-window-in-wpf) to for a way of getting the coordinates of the selected item relative to the `ListBox`.

Comment: I tested that, it's OK! Thanks a lot ;)