# Measure and Arrange a WPF control to use up available space

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a window that has a menu, a toolbar at the top, and various other controls. I then have my own control that derives from ContentControl that I want to have use up all remaining space. I can't leave it to its own devices unfortunately, because the control is a Win32 control that's sort of... put inside this WPF control, and I need to use SetWindowPos.

At the moment what I am doing is using ArrangeOverride, getting the MainWindow.Content control and looking at the Height and Width. I then use Size I get in as a parameter and call the SetWindowPos function. It's written in C++/CLI, and here's the code:

```
Size WebView::ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
            Application::Current->MainWindow->Measure(finalSize);
            UIElement^ obj = dynamic_cast<UIElement^>(Application::Current->MainWindow->Content);
            double objHei = obj->RenderSize.Height;
            double objWid = obj->RenderSize.Width;
            SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, objWid-finalSize.Width, objHei-finalSize.Height, finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height, NULL);
```

So in my head I thought this would then set the position of the control to within the remaining available space. And it does sort of work, but it seems as if the MainWindow.Content control is not being measured until afterwards? What am I doing wrong here?

edit: most of the problems seem to be when full-screening the window and then un-fullscreening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this by using the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386731/get-absolute-position-of-element-within-the-window-in-wpf)

I simply put my control into a Frame, so it'd be the parent.

Then using the Point I set the window position to that, along with the size that is passed through as a parameter to the ArrangeOverride method.