# Child window Positioning

Tags: c#, wpf, parent-child

I know this has been asked before ([Get Absolute Position of element within the window in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386731/get-absolute-position-of-element-within-the-window-in-wpf)) but I haven't been able to implement properly yet. I'm trying to have a child window open up relative to the control in the parent window. So far, I have this;

```
messageWindow = new Message(true);
Point relativePoint = btn1.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
messageWindow.Left = relativePoint.X;
messageWindow.Top = relativePoint.Y;
messageWindow.Show();
```

Now although this does effect the position of the child window (`messageWindow`), it doesn't seem to place it on/beside the `btn1` control in the parent. Another problem I have with it is that if I move the parent window, then recall this method having closed the original `messageWindow` the new instance of the window displays in the old position (even though `btn1` is in a new position). I find this odd and was wondering if anyone could help me fix this.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Charleh for explaining that I was only setting them relative to the control location in the window, not to the overall screen. So now it is a question of getting the parent window's location on the screen and adding it to the XY also. How would I get this? Just tried this code (although I'll be honest, I don't quite understand it) bus still doesn't seem to follow very closely. What's a good way of getting Window location on the screen?;

```
messageWindow= new Message(true);
Point relativePoint = btn1.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
PresentationSource ScreenPos = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);

messageWindow.Left = relativePoint.X + (96.0 * ScreenPos.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11);
messageWindow.Top = relativePoint.Y + (96.0 * ScreenPos.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22);
messageWindow.Show();
```

Comment: Are you taking into account the coordinates of the parent window? This only gives you the relative position for the child window - not the absolute position, it sounds like you need to place the child window at the same position as the parent window, then transform it using relativePoint

Comment: @Charleh Oh ya. That makes sense why it didn't move with the parent. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`relativePoint` is the position of the control *relative* to the `Window`, not the screen. When setting the `Left` and `Right` points of `messageWindow` (the child window), the points are *relative* to the screen, not the parent window.

In order to get the correct position, you'll need to find the position of the parent window and then do some math to find where the control is located relative to the screen, not the window which should give you the location of where you want to place the child window.

Comment: Sounds good, and how do I get the position of the window on the screen?

Comment: `this.Top` and `this.Left` will get the window's top/left edge in relation to the desktop (screen).

Comment: Duh! Think I'm half asleep today... Thanks :D

Comment: Keep in mind that the `TransformToAncestor` points will not take into account the window's chrome (title bar), so your math will need to accommodate that as well.

Comment: Good point, found `SystemParameters.CaptionHeight` which seems to hold the chrome height. Border is pretty negligible. Thanks again.