# convert from System.Windows.Shapes rectangle to system.drawing.rectangle c#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

How can I convert a System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle (WPF) to a System.Drawing.Rectangle (Windows Forms)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be rather pointless. A WPF `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` is an drawing shape, like a `Control`. A `System.Drawing.Rectangle` is a mathematical object that just describes the dimensions of a rectangular shape, not something to be drawn on the screen. It has no color, no actual representation on screen, etc.

Comment: alright, though how can I pass the arguments of a WPF rectangle to winForms rectangle? would it be possible cuz this later has a X,Y propreties when the first one doesn't!

Comment: The first has a height and length property, but not a position. You could [calculate that though](http://stackoverflow.com/q/386731/993547).